# How can I associate a value with each checkbox in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I have created a custom ListView using a custom adapter.  I have an xml file that defines each row, and each row has a checkbox defined in this xml file.  My app is a judging app where each item on the ListView is a "task" that counts for a certain number of points. The idea is that if the task is completed, then the judge clicks the checkbox, and the score of that task is added to an overall score.

Unfortunately, I see no way to get this value associated with the checkbox.  Is there a way to do this?  I'll post some code, and I hope it's enough to get the general idea of my issue.

The XML file for the row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/score_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/score_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        android:onClick="chkBoxClicked" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/subtask"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/score_box"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/max_points"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/subtask" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The method from the activity that creates the list:

```
    ...
public void createScoringList() {
    ListView scoreList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.score_list);
    ListView scoreListPartial = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.score_list_partial);
    ArrayList<ScoringInfo> objList = new ArrayList<ScoringInfo>();  
    ArrayList<ScoringInfo> objListPartial = new ArrayList<ScoringInfo>();
    ScoringInfo scrInfo;

    for (int i = 0; i < subTaskList.size(); i++) {
        subtask_num = subTaskList.get(i).subtask_num;
        max_points = subTaskList.get(i).max_points;
        partial_points_allowed = subTaskList.get(i).partial_points_allowed;
        task_name = subTaskList.get(i).task_name;

        scrInfo = new ScoringInfo();
        scrInfo.setMaxPoints("Max Points: " + max_points);
        scrInfo.setSubtask(task_name);

        if (partial_points_allowed == 1)
            objListPartial.add(scrInfo);
        else
            objList.add(scrInfo);
    }
    scoreList.setAdapter(new ScoreListAdapter(objList , this));
    scoreListPartial.setAdapter(new ScoreListAdapter2(objListPartial, this));

}
```

If more code is required for clarity, ask, and I will provide.  I just didn't want to overflow the question with loads of code that I think may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either store this value in your model (I think it's called ScoringInfo) or you can assign this value to every checkbox using `setTag("score", value)` method and read it by calling `getTag("score")`.

You can set and read tag in your adapter class like this. You adapter shall implement `OnClickListener` and manage list of `ScoringInfo` items.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.<your_layout>, parent, false);
    }

    ScoringInfo item = this.getItem(position);

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
    checkBox.setTag("score", item.max_points);
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view instanceof CheckBox) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        int score = view.getTag("score");
        // do the rest
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about adding it to the ScoringInfo object, and your set/getTag is good to know info, but if I'm not adding the checkboxes dynamically, how do I set a tag?  And the value is the max_points that's already added to my model, but I don't know how to designate it per each checkbox.  Would I create a new CheckBox item with the row's checkbox id and do it there?

Comment: Thank you! This helped point me in the right direction. A couple of things I had to do differently from your suggestion was implement a new OnClickListener in an inner class instead of using "this".  Also, Android/Java forces you to use a pre-compiled key when setting the tag, so I had to create a string in strings.xml to label the key as "score".